# What are this green letters in VS code? (version control)

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

A few days ago I changed something accidentally in the version control of vs code. Now this is showing at the left:

[image]

It doesn't affect my code but I would like to disable it, just to make sure that it doesn't affect future projects. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Those are uncommitted files (new files that you've never committed to the branch). It has no effect on your code. I'm afraid I don't know if there's a way to change this behaviour through

Comment: will this have any effects in the way I commit changes to github by using the command line?

Comment: No, everything will work as you expect